# .Net MessageBoxButtons any way to change the Yes/No order?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there any way to change the "MessageBoxButtons.YesNo" Yes/No order on .Net?

The **Yes** button is by default on the left and **No** button on the right, how can I change that?

My code

```
 MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to confirm?", "Problem!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: Because there's nothing better than confusing users by presenting them with a familiar dialog but subtly switching things around? Why would you *want* to do that?

Comment: Damien's comment hit the point, but the question is quite good for newbies and I think it does not deserve downvotes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I understand and I agree with you. But it's not me. I need to find if there's a way to do it, so I asked for help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that. Built-in message box functionality has only few moving parts: message text, title, help page and choice from predefined set of icons and button sets (not mentioning few other minor options).

If you want to suggest the user answer "No" as default one, go with Yes-No buttons and make No the default button using [`MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxdefaultbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) (use [this MessageBox.Show() overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctd56yay(v=vs.110).aspx)). This is [a standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742470(v=vs.85).aspx) in handling the need where answer No is preferred/recommended.

So based on your example, you can use

```c#
MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to confirm?",
                "Problem!",
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                 MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                 MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
```

Further reading: [User interface guidelines on confirmation dialogs at MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742470(v=vs.85).aspx)